# Will Silverlight run on ipad

Tags: silverlight, ios7

I looked all over the internet, but everything I found is from 3-4 years ago. Did this change? Can I make a Silverlight app and assume ipad will run it?

Comment: This did not change, Silverlight is a plugin (like Flash) and will not run on an iPad.

Comment: That makes me sad. Thank you though.